# How would you add a time stamp column to a Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp

Every time I append a dataframe to a text file, I want it to contain a column with the same timestamp for each row. The timestamp could be any arbitrary time as long as its different from next time when I append a new dataframe to the existing text file. Below code inserts a column named TimeStamp, but doesn't actually insert datetime values. The column is simply empty. I must be overlooking something simple. What am I doing wrong?

```
t = [datetime.datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0) for i in range(df.shape[0])]
s = pd.Series(t, name = 'TimeStamp')
df.insert(0, 'TimeStamp', s)
```

Comment: You just have some typos (see edits)... It works fine for me.

Comment: I don't see the typo in my code as no error was raised. The code ran fine, but I just get empty values

Comment: @Murchak, your code works fine for me. No empty values.

Comment: does `df.insert` operate in-place or return a copy? if it returns a copy, you'll need to capture the result

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think simpliest is use [`insert`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html) only:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': list('AAA'), 'B': range(3)}, index=list('xyz'))
print (df)
   A  B
x  A  0
y  A  1
z  A  2

df.insert(0, 'TimeStamp', pd.to_datetime('now').replace(microsecond=0))
print (df)
            TimeStamp  A  B
x 2018-02-15 07:35:35  A  0
y 2018-02-15 07:35:35  A  1
z 2018-02-15 07:35:35  A  2
```

---

Your working version - change `range(df.shape[0])` to `df.index` for same indices in `Series` and in `DataFrame`:

```
t = [datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(microsecond=0) for i in df.index]
s = pd.Series(t, name = 'TimeStamp')
df.insert(0, 'TimeStamp', s)
```

Comment: Thanks jezrael! Your solution above worked. However, changing my code to what your recommended (i in df.index) did not. It still gave me empty entries.

Comment: I have better solution. Give me a sec.

Comment: One quick note, df.datetime.now is being deprecated. Instead you could use 
`datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")`